# Calling email controller in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an image link which calls the email function in a controller in CakePHP. There is no email.ctp file. I'm directly sending email from the controller through PHPMailer.

When I click on the link the id gets displayed in the URL which I don't want to be displayed. I want the email to get sent from the index.ctp file without the id getting displayed in the URL. Below is my img link code.

```
$this->Html->image('webroot/img/email.png',
['alt'->'Email',
 'url'=>['controller' => 'Students', 
 'action' => 'email',
 $student=>id]
])
```

I have never sent an email before.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The ID is displayed in the URL because you have included the ID in the URL. Who are you sending email to in this instance? If it's the student, then you obviously need to get the ID to the controller somehow. Also, `index.ctp` can't "send" email. Are you perhaps picturing an Ajax type of scenario, where a request (including the ID) is sent to the server without the page being reloaded?

Comment: The email is sent but without any confirmation from the user. Any idea how to get a jQuery or bootstrap pop up which asks the user to confirm and then email once the user clicks Yes?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. I had not included the PHPMailer files properly